# how to properly pass _set_ of parameters with spaces into shell function

Tags: shell-script, shell, quoting, parameter

My problem is not simple passing parameters with spaces (I know how to achieve that), consider more complicated case:

```
function build() {
  make CC="$1" CFLAGS="$2" $* # $* is not correct here!
}

build gcc "XXX" VAR1="a b" VAR2="c=A d=B" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/lib -lm"
```

as equivalent to

```
make CC=gcc CFLAGS=XXX VAR1="a b" VAR2="c=A d=B" LDFLAGS="-L/opt/lib -lm"
```

I would like to achieve this one to work in shell (portable solutions please, no bashisms, etc). Any suggestions, recommendations?

Comment: And, why aren't you using `"$@"` which is designed exactly for this purpose?

Comment: Forget about `$*` and remember `"$@"` instead. `"$@"` is very often useful whereas `"$*"` is very rarely useful and the unquoted forms are even rarer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two elements to a better solution:

- `shift`
- (more) quoting

Define the function using `shift`, like this:

```
function build {
  local cc="$1"
  local cflags="$2"
  shift 2
  make CC="$cc" CFLAGS="$cflags" "$@"
}
```

where we save the first two parameters to local variables, then shift the whole argument array by two; also, quote the "$@" expansion.

Then, call it with extra quoting, like this:

```
build gcc "XXX" 'VAR1="a b" VAR2="c=A d=B"' 'LDFLAGS="-L/opt/lib -lm"'
```

where the single quotes protect the extra arguments into the function; otherwise, the shell removes the quotes and you'd be left with `VAR2=c=A d=B` (unquoted) in the function.

Comment: He probably wants `"$@"`, not `"$*"`.

Comment: Thanks, man! I mistakenly quoted arguments (yes, I played with `"$@"`) like `VAR2='"c=A d=B"'`. I will check a bit later today and mark answer. Btw, shouldn't your example contain couple more single quotes?

Comment: That's not fully correct due to inheritance of the double quotes to the later parameters, means that argument of VAR2 becomes `"c=A d=B"` instead of `c=A d=B` in the internals of *Makefile*, for now it still works when I dropped double quotes in the quoting, i.e. `'VAR2=c=A d=B'`.